# SQL GROUP BY Statement csv export shows incorrect sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, csv

Running query in SQL Server 2012 and exporting cost records in csv by save result as option, query is shown here:

```
SELECT 
    ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,..,
    SUM(COST_REPORTING.Actual_Cost) AS Actual_Cost
FROM 
    Table_Name AS Table_Name 
WHERE 
    USAGESTARTDATE >='2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'  
    AND USAGEENDDATE<='2018-05-31 12:00:00.000'
GROUP BY 
    ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,..,
```

Sum of all Actual_Cost records in csv shows 1817751.612

However if I just save Actual_Cost Column as csv the results while checking SUM for all cost records is 1823065.094, query below:

```
SELECT
    Z.Actual_Cost 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,..,
         SUM(COST_REPORTING.Actual_Cost) AS Actual_Cost
     FROM 
         Table_Name AS Table_Name 
     WHERE 
         USAGESTARTDATE >='2018-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
         AND USAGEENDDATE<='2018-05-31 12:00:00.000'
     GROUP BY ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,..,) AS Z
```

I have also checked using SQL Query the sum for all ACTUAL_COST Records shows as 1823065.094, query below:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Z.Actual_Cost ) AS SUM_Actual_Cost
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,...,
        SUM(COST_REPORTING.Actual_Cost) AS Actual_Cost
    FROM 
        Table_Name AS Table_Name 
    WHERE 
        USAGESTARTDATE >='2018-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
        AND USAGEENDDATE<='2018-05-31 12:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY 
         ...,...,...,...,...,......,...,..,...,) AS Z
```

Actual_Cost Column datatype is float in DB.

Why does the csv with all columns shows Actual_Cost sum as 1817751.612 instead of 1823065.094 and how can I correct it ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format your code. This is unreadable.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, all as formatted text - not images. But first take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you for the heads up @Evaldas Buinauskas .. I have made a few changes and took out all string columns

Answer (score 0):

try putting an explicit `CAST(Actual_Cost AS DECIMAL(18,5))` in your query (or some other large datatype) and see if it helps

Comment: I have already tried CAST(Actual_Cost AS DECIMAL(18,5)) and Actual_Cost AS DECIMAL(38,20)).... Still Thank you :)

Comment: When I am trying to copy the Actual_Cost results from grid in SQL and paste to excel they show sum as 1823065.094 , so I finally I wrote a JDBC service to extract the same data and write it to csv and guess what the sum was ? -> 1823065.094..... It looks like that exporting heavy records from SQL server in file was affecting the numbers somehow :)

Comment: Just tried copying all columns from grid and pasting it excel .. sum for all Actual Cost Records shows 1823065.094... Nice WorkAround :)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried copying all columns from grid instead of saving it as file and pasting it in Excel .. sum for all Actual Cost Records shows 1823065.094...

I know it is not Solid Fix but Nice WorkAround :)